# A minimum OSPFv3 config of BIRD routers from topology

Tags: ospf, linux

[image: topology]

I'm experimenting with BIRD, and I want to converge  simple network topology. I wonder how a minimal configuration file bird6.conf should look so that, for example, PC 1 can reach network between R2 and R4 and so on. I don't want any filters or other features, I am curious only about the reachability of the network nodes.

I have learned the concept of how the BIRD works, but I don't know which steps leads to converged network. For example on Cisco routers, you just type the directly connected networks, and router will advertise these, or with ospfv3 it's a similar problem, but in place of networks you type just interfaces. So I don't know if I am supposed to write just interfaces with assigned IPv6 addr into bird6.conf or should I write interfaces and directly connected networks, or neighbors etc.

Here is my try of R1 router.. Is this supposed to work or not? If not, so what is missing? I would like to, if you someone could post the minimal config of router R1, so I can learn from it, or just write basic steps what add into config file.

```
log syslog all;

router id 1.1.1.1;

protocol device {
    scan time 10;
}

protocol kernel {
    export all;
    scan time 15;
}


protocol ospf MyOSPF {

    import all;



    area 0 {
            interface "eth0" {
                    cost 5;
                    type broadcast;
                    hello 5; retransmit 2; wait 10; dead 20;
            };


    };
}
```